# Implementation of `ulp` and `nextAfter` for platforms where these are missing

Tags: java, floating-point

I need [the `ulp` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29) in Codename ONE, and since it isn't available there, I tried to come up with my own version. The code is completely written from scratch, based solely on the documentation of the `java.lang.Math` class.

Please ignore the `@Override` annotations. This is from a utility class I wrote to be able to use the same code for Java SE and Codename ONE development (this obviously is the Codename ONE version).

```
private static final double MAX_ULP = com.codename1.util.MathUtil.pow(2.0, 971);

@Override
public double ulp(double d) {
    if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
        // If the argument is NaN, then the result is NaN.
        return Double.NaN;
    } else if (Double.isInfinite(d)) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative infinity, then the
        // result is positive infinity.
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    } else if (d == 0.0) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is Double.MIN_VALUE.
        return Double.MIN_VALUE;
    } else if (d == Double.MAX_VALUE || d == -Double.MAX_VALUE) {
        //If the argument is ±Double.MAX_VALUE, then the result is equal to 2^971.
        return MAX_ULP;
    } else {
        d = Math.abs(d);
        return nextAfter(d, Double.MAX_VALUE) - d;
    }
}

@Override
public double copySign(double x, double y) {
    return com.codename1.util.MathUtil.copysign(x, y);
}

private boolean isSameSign(double x, double y) {
    return copySign(x, y) == x;
}

@Override
public double nextAfter(double start, double direction) {
    if (Double.isNaN(start) || Double.isNaN(direction)) {
        // If either argument is a NaN, then NaN is returned.
        return Double.NaN;
    } else if (start == direction) {
        // If both arguments compare as equal the second argument is returned.
        return direction;
    } else if ((start == Double.MIN_VALUE || start == -Double.MIN_VALUE)
            && (!isSameSign(start, direction) || Math.abs(direction) < Math.abs(start))) {
        // If start is ±Double.MIN_VALUE and direction has a value such that
        // the result should have a smaller magnitude, then a zero with
        // the same sign as start is returned.
        return copySign(0.0, start);
    } else if (Double.isInfinite(start) && !Double.isInfinite(direction)) {
        // If start is infinite and direction has a value such that the
        // result should have a smaller magnitude, Double.MAX_VALUE with
        // the same sign as start is returned.
        return copySign(Double.MAX_VALUE, start);
    } else if ((start == Double.MAX_VALUE || start == -Double.MAX_VALUE)
            && (Double.isInfinite(direction) && isSameSign(start, direction))) {
        // If start is equal to ± Double.MAX_VALUE and direction has a
        // value such that the result should have a larger magnitude, an
        // infinity with same sign as start is returned.
        return start > 0.0 ? Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY : Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    } else if (start==0.0) {
        return copySign(Double.MIN_VALUE, direction);
    } else {
        long d = ((direction > start) == (start>=0)) ? 1L : -1L;
        long x = Double.doubleToLongBits(start) + d;
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(x);
    }

}
```

PS: I wrote this code from scratch (for licence reasons), so if anybody has a use for this, feel free to use and modify it in your own projects.

**EDIT:** The code I originally posted still had an error I found after checking all corner cases against the JDK version. I had to introduce another check for `start==0.0` in `nextAfter` to get all unit tests pass. Also, the condition for setting `d` was flawed.

Comment: Never edit the code in the question in response to an answer, as that invalidates the answer. Here are some [options for follow-ups](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357).

Comment: May bug?  I am concerned about `nextAfter(d, Double.MAX_VALUE) - d;` potential returning zero on a system that does not employ sub-normals when `d` is very small.  I am uncertain about Java requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks neat enough, well formatted, etc. That's great. There is one common issue you have in your code, and that is the else-if for early-return blocks.

The code:

```
if (conditionA) {
    ... do something
    return something;
} else if (conditionB) {
    ... do something
    return something;
} else if .....
```

has redundant if blocks. The logic is right, but, it would be better as:

```
if (conditionA) {
    ... do something
    return something;
}
if (conditionB) {
    ... do something
    return something;
}
if .....
```

You have that pattern in a lot of places.

A second general concern I have is that you do not specify 'final' for your parameters in places where it can make sense. The 'final' concept is debatable for performance, but I have found that it makes a difference in both the disciple, and occasionally the performance. For example, the function:

> ```
> private boolean isSameSign(double x, double y) {
>     return copySign(x, y) == x;
> }
> ```

would be better as:

```
private boolean isSameSign(final double x, final double y) {
    return copySign(x, y) == x;
}
```

### `ulp()`

It would be convenient in your ULP to do the `d = Math.abs(d)` earlier in the function as it simplifies some logic. Consider the following:

```
public double ulp(final double input) {
    final double d = Math.abs(input);
    if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
        // If the argument is NaN, then the result is NaN.
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    if (Double.isInfinite(d)) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative infinity, then the
        // result is positive infinity.
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    if (d == 0.0) {
        // If the argument is positive or negative zero, then the result is Double.MIN_VALUE.
        return Double.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    if (d == Double.MAX_VALUE) {
        //If the argument is ±Double.MAX_VALUE, then the result is equal to 2^971.
        return MAX_ULP;
    }
    return nextAfter(d, Double.MAX_VALUE) - d;
}
```

I assume that your research on \$2^{971}\$ is accurate for `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

### `copySign()`

**Edit:** This method confused me, and lead me to introduce a bug in my code (now fixed).

It is my opinion that the arguments are the wrong way around. I would expect `copySign(x, y)` to copy the sign from `x` to `y`, but your code implements it the other way around. Instead of arguments `x` and `y`, they should have better names, and the method should be named differently as well:

```
public double copySignToFrom(final double target, final double sign) {...}
```

My preference would be to just reverse the arguments, but that method is overridden, and the implementation is not actually shown here (Note: Show all your code next time...).

### `nextAfter()`

Again, like `ulp()`, this function would benefit from removing the 'else if' construct. The early return makes it unnecessary.

The logic in here looks good. I have tried to see if there's a better way of doing things, and, I think there may be... by recording the signs of the start & direction, you can do all the math in absolute terms, and re-conevrt the signs later.... It's a toss up as to whether the performance will be better to do the conversion each time, and then have simpler conditions on the logic.

So, the only real criticism I have here is the `else if`, but, for interest, consider the following:

**Edit:** *revised my code example because of copySign usage bug...*

```
public class DoublePlay {

    private static final long MASK = Long.MIN_VALUE;

//    @Override
    public double copySign(double target, double source) {
        if ((Double.doubleToLongBits(target) & MASK) == (Double.doubleToLongBits(source) & MASK)) {
            return target;
        }
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(target) ^ MASK);
    }

    private boolean isSameSign(double x, double y) {
        return copySign(x, y) == x;
    }

    public double nextAfter(final double start, final double direction) {
        if (Double.isNaN(start) || Double.isNaN(direction)) {
            // If either argument is a NaN, then NaN is returned.
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        if (start == direction) {
            // If both arguments compare as equal the second argument is returned.
            return direction;
        }

        final double absstart = Math.abs(start);
        final double absdir = Math.abs(direction);
        final boolean tozero = !isSameSign(start, direction) || absdir < absstart;

        if (tozero) {
            // we are reducing the magnitude, going toward zero.
            if (absstart == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                return copySign(0.0, start);
            }
            if (Double.isInfinite(absstart)) {
                return copySign(Double.MAX_VALUE, start);
            }
            return copySign(Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(absstart) - 1L), start);
        }

        // we are increasing the magnitude, toward +-Infinity
        if (absstart == Double.MAX_VALUE) {
            return copySign(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, start);
        }
        return copySign(Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToLongBits(absstart) +1L), start);

    }

    private static final void testValue(DoublePlay dp, final double base, final double direction) {
        double result = dp.nextAfter(base, direction);
        System.out.printf("From: %016x %s%nStep: %016x %s%nTo  : %016x %s%n%n", 
                Double.doubleToLongBits(base), String.valueOf(base),
                Double.doubleToLongBits(direction), String.valueOf(direction),
                Double.doubleToLongBits(result), String.valueOf(result)
                );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoublePlay dp = new DoublePlay();
        testValue(dp, Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        testValue(dp, Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        testValue(dp, -Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        testValue(dp, -Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
    }

}
```

The above code makes the decision 'early' about whether the magnitude of the `nextAfter()` is increasing (to infinity), or decreasing (to zero). It simplifies the rest of the conditions.

**Added an [Ideone with the code](http://ideone.com/lWckUr) as well**

Comment: I am used to the `if`-blocks in this style, but I will take your advice and have changed my code. Same for final parameters. In the meantime I wrote unit tests for both methods, and if I use your version of `nextAfter`, they break for `assertEquals(2*Double.MIN_VALUE, inst.nextAfter(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE), 0.0);`. But to be fair, my original code also had an error, I will fix it in the original post.

Comment: I am on my way out, but just saw I have an incorrect use-call for copySign.... needs a fix. I will update in a few hours.

Comment: @Axel - added note abour copySign, updated the nextAfter code, and included ideone

Comment: Is the only change you made is adding the `if (absstart==0){...}` block? I am not sure why that is needed. I am going to check it myself. Your tests are great, by the way. Very useful.

Comment: Yes. And I honestly didn't see why it is needed... ;-)